Error "Could not create a new virtual machine. 'New Virtual Machine' could not be implemented" when trying to create a VM in Hyper-V
Error description
Previously, virtual machines in Hyper-V were created without problems. After that, I did not disable Hyper-v, tried to use various images: Windows, Ubuntu, etc., but recently an error began to appear, I attached a screenshot. So I don't know what could be the reason for this behavior of Hyper-v

Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block.
